# Using "dontwarn" in proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I use proguard successfully but whenever I add external library (those that belongs to advertising) proguard fails with "can't find reference ...etc". I tried many combination such as libraryjars, injars ...etc but no luck.

Then I used the  " -dontwarn " option on the external file and things worked magically. Is this bad to do? I mean is there a problem I am not seeing with handling external jars using this attribute?

Thank you

Comment: Where did you add "-dontwarn" in proguard file? Exactly what line? and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For warnings about missing third-party classes, the options `-ignorewarnings` or `-dontwarn` are probably fine. If the code already works in debug mode, it means that the listed missing classes are never used. You can then tell ProGuard to proceed processing the code anyway.

For warnings about missing Android runtime classes, fields, or methods, you should build against a sufficiently recent Android runtime, specified in `project.properties`. You can still target an older Android runtime in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting:

- [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
- [Warning: can't find referenced field/method '...' in library class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

Note that you should not add `-injars` or `-libraryjars` options to your configuration, since the standard Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build processes automatically specify these for you.

Comment: Thank you Eric. but the problem that it complains about classes being referenced by the external jar and the classes/methods used are in the standard android library (like android.View)

Comment: I've extended the answer for warnings about missing Android classes and methods .