# libgdx Didn't find class. How to fix the error?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, classnotfoundexception

I decided to try to test the game on my phone, but I can't understand what my error is.
 
1. I download [demo](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper) 
 
2. Open project in Android studio 
 
3. and try to run on android.
 
But Android studio says:

```
08-30 16:42:01.252 18553-18553/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android, PID: 18553
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android.AndroidLauncher}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android.AndroidLauncher" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android.AndroidLauncher" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:326)
```

what am I doing wrong ?
 
The documentation says :
[image]

But even if I create empty project, there is the exact same error.

Comment: post your project level and app level gradel files

Comment: Not sure what you want. How to do it ?

Comment: See this image and navigate to gradle files and post them down here. What's your project package-name?

Comment: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx22Om2DGhBGVFNSMEZOZnNKeUE) to project files. All gradle files there.

Comment: How you open your project, make sure you've imported through gradle.

Comment: i'll import by "Go to Import Project (File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources), navigate to your project folder and select the build.gradle file. Hit OK." . Try to build by "gradlew android:installDebug android:run"  Same problem

Answer (score 0):

I tested both project on github, and your provided project. I successfully ran both on my Android device 6.0 via Android Studio `2.3.3` without a need to modify anything.

---

Let's get into it. As seen here

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android.AndroidLauncher" on path
```

I guess it just strips away your class as optimizing process kicks in.
So you may try to firstly clean your project, then adding a proguard rule to your `android` target as following steps.

1.) Set up proguard rule in `build.gradle` of `android` by editing `android/build.gradle` file to be as follows

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion project.androidToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion project.androidSDKVersion.toInteger()
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Only added section is entire `buildTypes { }` at the end.
`minifyEnabled` set to `false` to not obfuscate your code, as we don't need at the moment, but thing to pay attention to is `proguard-rules.pro` file as specified for `proguardFiles`.

2.) Create `proguard-rules.pro` file at `android/` path with following content.

```
-keep class com.badlogic.** { *; }
-keep enum com.badlogic.** { *; }
```

It will keep all classes, and enum to **not** be stripped away.

3.) Sync the project, and run it again.

**Note**

Normally for libgdx projects I've worked on, rarely I need to do just above. Doing as in step 2 would likely increase much of the app size anyway, so be careful with it. Just try the steps above to see if the problem goes away, then you can pin-point the problem down and try to introduce more optimized and better rules later.

The default working proguard rules for libgdx project is as following

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

You can know more about `-dontwarn` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796659/571227).

Comment: The error clearly needs to be in something else.
Even when creating an empty project this error appears.
However, if i start on the PC version, everything works fine.
P.S. I tried your solution, didn't help. A different error occurs now with gradle. Thanks

Comment: Which version of android studio you use? And can you also show the error for when you tried my solution?

Comment: 1:53 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'androidToolsVersion' for project ':android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: i'll try to use IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3 and Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Ok, let me know how things go.